# Javascript dropdown button with a scrollover

Tags: javascript, dropdownbox

I'm new to Javascript (and coding in general). I've been going through w3schools trying to learn a bit about Javascript. I've been attempting to build a button with a hover over effect that drops down text on click, and pulls it back up when clicked again. I'm attempting to place it on one of my pages so I can have some text for SEO without having it bog up the page. So far, I have figured out how to toggle text, but have not had any luck with actual buttons or the drop effect. Any assistance or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Show Text";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "HIDE TEXT";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Show Text

TEXT GOES HERE

Comment: are you looking for dropdown menu  ? Your questions is not much clear.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_putdropdown

Comment: Not quite, but that is pretty awesome and I'm gonna check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options for animation effects - CSS transition effects or something coded in JavaScript.

**CSS Transitions:**

You can add transitions to your CSS so that if numerical attributes of an element change (e.g. height, opacity), the browser will animate it so that if, for example you change height from 0px to 10px and set your transition time to 1 second, after 0.1 seconds it will change to 1px, after 0.2 seconds it will change to 2px, etc.  You can read the specifics of implementing CSS transitions here: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

**JavaScript**

You could write your own custom function, but if you're doing more than one animation in your life it's probably more time-efficient to learn to use a custom JavaScript library like jQuery.  The entire function you've written above could be rewritten as `$('#ele').slideToggle();`

---

Unrelated to your specific question, the method you have above won't matter for SEO since Google won't see the text you add with JavaScript - and from what I understand Google may not like the hidden text too much either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I should be more specific. A good example of what I am talking about I found on Godaddy.coms home page. If you scroll down there is a gray button that says "more about domains" under an image of some employees in black all hugging. I talked to them about that and they said they do that for content, and its not technically hidden its just a dynamic section of the page thats clearly listed. I'm trying to figure out how they did that. I assume they used ASP, but I was hoping there was a way to do it with javascript.

Comment: It's doable with JavaScript - people on SO won't write the code for you but can point you in the right direction or fix broken code - those were the two directions I'd look at if I were you.  As for making sure it works for SEO, a lot more people claim to understand how Google's ranking algorithm works than actually do, so (even without knowing the 'best' way to do what you're trying to do for SEO) I'd take what they're saying with a grain of salt.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the advice. I'll dig deeper at w3schools and see what I can find. Is there another good place where I can tutor myself in javascript other than w3?

Comment: w3schools is the best place I've found to start learning JavaScript.  For specific questions, though, Stack Overflow is the place to be :)